# [java.lang.ClassCastException: CustomPortlet incompatible with javax.portlet.Portlet

Tags: java, classcastexception, websphere-portal, myeclipse

I tried creating portlet using MyEclipse following [MyEclipse tutorial](http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/portlet_overview/). I did all the stesps and exported project as WAR. When installed it to the Portal and put it on a page, it said "This portlet is unavailable".

Find the related discussion [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=f2595af5-c246-40e4-879d-e584b587bfd1&ps=25).

**The exception is:   SRVE0068E: An exception was thrown by one of the service methods of the servlet [CustomPortlet] in application [PA_Vijay]. Exception created : [java.lang.ClassCastException: CustomPortlet incompatible with javax.portlet.Portlet**

This is my java code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.portlet.GenericPortlet;
import javax.portlet.PortletConfig;
import javax.portlet.PortletException;
import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;
import javax.portlet.UnavailableException;


public class CustomPortlet extends GenericPortlet {

    /**
     * Helper method to serve up the view mode.
     */

    public void init(PortletConfig pc)throws UnavailableException, PortletException{

        super.init(pc);
    }

    protected void doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response)
            throws PortletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.print("<p>This is the custom portlet created from MyEclipseIDE</p>");
    }

}
```

Where lies the problem?

Comment: Have you implemented javax.portlet.Portlet in your CustomPortlet?

Comment: No.  I'm downvoting this.  There's no code here.  Only an error message, and some links to other stuff...

Comment: Yes. I extended GenericPortlet which implements it.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you don't deploy the portlet-api.jar with your application. If you deploy it with your application it can cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Portlet capability in eclipse is probably creating the project for Pluto server. The jars in the lib folder maybe conflicting with the Websphere Portal runtime.

1. Empty the Web-INF/lib folder and give it shot.
2. Or you could just create a Dynamic Web project and mimic the  file/folder structure from a working websphere portlet sample
3. Or import a websphere portal sample portlet and modify that to suit your needs.

Hope this helps